# How to implement footnotes of a text in relational database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm relatively new to programming and database design, so for the sake of learning and practice, I was planning to develop an "e-library" web-app. Simply, that would be a collection of fully searchable books, paginated as in printed editions, with an admin panel to add and edit them.

But in the very beginning, I'm stuck with the implementation of footnotes in database, since they're part of the text and I don't know should I separate them in additional table or maybe process them later!?

I was also learning MongoDB, and it seems easy to implement them with nesting. But I want to know how to do that with relational databases.

Comment: You've picked one type of data, document data, that is not a good fit for a relational database.  You could put the footnote data in a relational database if and only if you want to see how many times a particular work is cited, which is important with scholarly articles.

Comment: What application relationships and queries are you interested in that involve footnotes? What does "fully searchable" mean? When footnotes are "implemented with nesting", what functionality does that give, and what functionality do you want? It seems you need to read some introductions to relational database design and to MongoDB. When you have the basics, you can express the structured parts of a [MongoDB database of nested and interrelated collections of documents](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_overview.htm) as a relational design.